# DataGrid data disappears when trying to sort

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a data grid that receives its binding from a List<List<>>, the binding works well and all the data shows.

for some reason, when clicking on the header in order to sort or when rolling the scroll wheel, all the data suddenly disappears.

This is some of the code:

The grid in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
</Window.Resources>   

<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"  AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height ="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="5"  BorderThickness="0" Background="AliceBlue" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

data binding:

```
CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = GetterSetter.CMinfo;
```

**Update:** I managed to solve the scroll wheel problem: need to set EnableRowVirtualization to "False"

Comment: Are there any blank rows in data?  Sorting will bring a all the blank row to the top of the grid so it appears there is no data.

Comment: It is possible in large queries, but even if i only query 1 system, which results in 1 row, it happens

Comment: If your source iGetterSetter.CMinfo; then you should sort the source.  Are you sure you are getting only one row as source?  Does a 
Vertical Scroll Bar appear.  If there is a scroll bar then you probably don't have only one row.

Comment: There is no scroll bar and the table consists of only one row, if i try to add a system that is not found by the query then an empty row appears (which also disappears when sorting). If I want to sort the source, is there anything special I need to do?

Comment: No.  Just make sure the view dates updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i Figured out what was my problem,
My data grid was showing on a new window and after the window launched I cleared the data from the List I was sourcing (in order to not have duplicate rows when making a new search), instead of doing so in the beginning of the method.

It made my grid sourcing from a List that was empty (even though it showed well in the new window).

I just moved the Clear() method to the beginning of the method and now everything works well.